# Product Version in WiX 3.5 and Visual Studio WiX Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.5

In another question about setting the Product Version attribute for a WiX installer ([How can I set the WiX installer version to the current build version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626033/how-can-i-set-the-wix-installer-version-to-the-curent-build-version)), the most voted answer (which I've tried and works) recommends:

*"You could use `Product/@Version="!(bind.FileVersion.<FileId>)"` and light.exe will populate the value with the version of the file referenced by the FileId."*

...which is great, but appears slightly brittle in Visual Studio WiX projects when using the harvesting capabilities of the WiX VS project in that the FileId for an executable **might** change.

Is there a safer way of referencing a specific file from the auto-generated .wxs files in Visual Studio other than using the FileVersion Preprocessor Extension (http://wixfileversionext.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the generated .wxs file through the XSL transform (the `-t` option of `heat.exe`), which will replace the auto-generated file ID with the one you choose. As a result, you'll be able to safely reference it from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

We use our build system to control all the versioning, and pass it into the WiX project as a msbuild property.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <version_major Condition=" '$(version_major)' == '' ">0</version_major>
    <version_minor Condition=" '$(version_minor)' == '' ">0</version_minor>
    <build_number Condition=" '$(build_number)' == '' ">0</build_number>
    <build_vcs_number Condition=" '$(build_vcs_number)' == '' ">0</build_vcs_number>
    <InstallerVersion>$(version_major).$(version_minor).$(build_number).0</InstallerVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and reference that in the WiX source with `Product/@Version="$(var.InstallerVersion)"`. That would work if your build system also controls the versioning of your binaries.