# Binding WIX FileVersion sub values?

Tags: wix

In WIX, I can do this to automatically generate a decent version number for my MSI:

```
<?define ProductVersion="!(bind.FileVersion.MyMainExecutable)" ?>
<Product Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" ... />
```

That produces a string like "1.0.1.0" but I want only the first three parts: "1.0.1"

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set the WiX installer version to the curent build version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626033/how-can-i-set-the-wix-installer-version-to-the-curent-build-version)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I've already scrutinized that answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a way to only get the first three fields of a bound `FileVersion`. However, if you are okay assigning the four part version to the `Product/@Version` (which is completely valid, although major upgrades will only look at the first three fields) then you can access each part of the major, minor, build, and revision using the following variables:

```
!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major)
!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Minor)
!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Build)
!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Revision)
```

Hopefully that can be useful.

Comment: So I could set the title of my installer to something like this? `"My Installer v!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major).!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Minor).!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Build)"`

Comment: I believe `WIX` should support reading the version fields of binaries. E.g. `...TargetFileName.ProductVersion.Major`

Comment: I believe your first comment should work. The second comment is a reasonable feature request. :)

Comment: Any chance for such a feature in 3.8? :) I solved it using a powershell script but it sure would be nice if WIX could do it.

Comment: Absolutely possible. WiX v3.8 hasn't shipped yet.

Comment: Has this feature request been logged somewhere? I don't see it in v3.8?

Comment: It is not likely that someone logged a feature request for you. Possible but not likely. :)

Comment: @l33t Did you ever get this to work? I assume so from the accepted anwser, I tried your top comment here, and just get "Unresolved bind-time variable" - any ideas? (WiX v3.11) - I am trying to use in the Name attribute of the Product element. It appears to work elsewhere, but I want my title something like that.

Comment: I also don't see any 'Title' element in WiX so I'm not sure what you mean by this?