# WIX: get version of setup upto buildversion

Tags: wix

We can get the productversion in wix using `!(bind.fileVersion.Product.exe)`. This returns the version as `3.8.2363.0`. How can I get the version up to build version, i.e. `3.8.2363.`

I followed [Binding WIX FileVersion sub values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006466/binding-wix-fileversion-sub-values) this link, but using 
"!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major)" do not solve my problem.

```
<?define ProductVersion123="!(bind.fileVersion.mainexe_dll)" ?>
<Product Id="{7BDF78BF-95E8-4ABB-8A0F-4A1483D7FDD1}" Name="SpreadsheetConverter !(bind.property.ProductVersion123.Major)" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.property.ProductVersion123.Major)" Manufacturer="ABC" UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)" Codepage="1252">
```

This gives error:

**Unresolved bind-time variable Mainexe !(bind.property.ProductVersion123.Major).**

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding WIX FileVersion sub values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006466/binding-wix-fileversion-sub-values)

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize what !(bind.property.X) does.  It retrieves the value of the X property from the MSI's Property table.  You have not setup a ProductVersion123 property in the MSI, you have created a WiX preprocessor variable ProductVersion123.

So what you have to do is assign the Product's Version attribute to $(var.ProductVersion123) (which sets the ProductVersion property of the MSI).  Now you can access that with !(bind.property.ProductVersion), including the !(bind.property.ProductVersion.X) extensions.