# Wix Installer with Major Version Subfolder

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I have the following code in my Product.wxs file

```
<Wix>
    <?define ProductVersion="!(bind.fileVersion._957E198E_2074_A3FA_A554_6FE5D8E9F4FD)" ?>
    <?define MajorVersion="!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major)" ?>

    <Product Id='*' Name='Software v$(var.MajorVersion)' Version='$(var.ProductVersion)' Manufacturer='...' UpgradeCode='...' Codepage='...'>
    [...]
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

The above is based on this [Binding WIX FileVersion sub values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006466/binding-wix-fileversion-sub-values) question's answer.

It gives me the following error though
[image: Light Compile Error]

My Plan B was smth like

```
<?define MajorVersion="!(bind.fileVersion._957E198E_2074_A3FA_A554_6FE5D8E9F4FD.Major)" ?>
```

or

```
<?define MajorVersion="!(bind.fileVersion.major._957E198E_2074_A3FA_A554_6FE5D8E9F4FD)" ?>
```

but those don't work either.

Ultimately I want to use the `MajorVersion` property/variable to be part of the install directory.
`<CustomAction Id='DIRCA_TARGETDIR' Property='TARGETDIR' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[MajorVersion]\[ProductName]' Execute='firstSequence' />`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I eventually found an answer myself.

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <?define MainAssemblyVersion="!(bind.fileVersion._957E198E_2074_A3FA_A554_6FE5D8E9F4FD)" ?>
  <?define MajorVersion="!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major)" ?>

  <Product Id='*' Name='Software v$(var.MajorVersion' Language='1033' Version='$(var.MainAssemblyVersion)' Manufacturer='...' UpgradeCode='...' Codepage='...'>
    [...]
    <!-- Initialize the 'TARGETDIR' directory property. -->
    <CustomAction Id='DIRCA_TARGETDIR' Property='TARGETDIR' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName] v$(var.MajorVersion)' Execute='firstSequence' />
    [...]
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

I believe I was partly confused by the fact that `bind.property.ProductVersion` already exists and doesn't have to be declared (which I did in my first example)

Once you have the major version part in a variable, using it `$(var.MainAssemblyVersion)` is really all it needs.