# Displaying MSI version parts at the Wix Burn Bundle level (to display in title / caption)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix3.11

I've discovered how to access the parts within the MSI/Product tag. But my goal was to set the caption of the burn installer based on the Major/Minor version number.

This code below is the summary of what I tried to do, but this doesn't work (I think because I'm not within the Product tag).

Burn wxs:

```
<Wix>
<Bundle Version="!(bind.packageVersion.<packageName>)" >

    <Variable Name="ProductVersionMajor" Value="!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major)"/>
    <Variable Name="ProductVersionMinor" Value="!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Minor)"/>
....
```

Theme.wxl:

```
<WixLocalization ...>
  <String Id="Caption">[WixBundleName] [ProductVersionMajor].[ProductVersionMinor] Setup</String>
....
```

Is there some kind of work around where I can get this information at the bundle level without writing custom code?

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006466/binding-wix-fileversion-sub-values) was useful, but not quite what it appears I need; since I'm not within the WIX product tag for the inner MSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major)` is a bind variable when building an MSI, not a bundle. The available bind variables are documented at https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html. There is an open feature request for MsiPackage property bind variables at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4298. It would likely be additional work to get the `ProductVersion.Whatever` part working, so if you want that then you should add a comment to that issue.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to pull out information at the bundle level for the MSI level?
No alternative work arounds that you may know of?

Thanks Sean!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sean's answer, if you are only interested in the full version and not in any breakdown of major/minor/build then the below example I have the caption in the localization WXL file can be defined as simple as:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" Language="1033" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
    <String Id="Caption">[WixBundleName] Setup (v. [WixBundleVersion])</String>
...
```

and in my bundle.wxs file I have the following definition:

```
<Bundle Name="$(var.MyProductFullName)"
      Version="!(bind.packageVersion.MyPackageId)"
      Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.MyPackageId)">
...
```

where the variable MyProductFullName is defined in my variables file under my package's installer project. So basically the ***[WixBundleName]***
and ***[WixBundleVersion]*** are bound to the Bundle element's ***Name*** and ***Version*** attribute values, respectively.