# Automatically update version info in wix installer

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, version

Hi I have a C/C++ Header file with my products version info init as follows:

```cpp
#define nMajorVersion 4
#define nMinorVersion 4
#define nPointVersion 8
#define nBuildVersion 33
#define s_szFileVersion "4.4.8.33"
#define s_szProductVersion "4.4.8.33"
```

Is there any way I can automatically read from this file to update my version number in my wix 3.6 installer? At the moment I have it hard coded and this is not ideal for when it is released. Thanks

Comment: how about writing a c/c++ program to rewrite the version numbers in the wxs file?

Comment: @Wimmel I thought the version was set at build time? Is this incorrect?

Comment: yes, so you run a program to update the wxs file just before it is build. In your situation you already have a custom header file, so I don't think anything out of the box will solve your problem. I''ll add an answer which allows me better the explain what I mean.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/626033/145173) (doesn't assume a generated header file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is create a c/c++ program which generates a file `Version.wxi` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <?define ProductVersion.Major="4"?>
  <?define ProductVersion.Minor="4"?>
  <?define ProductVersion.Revision="8"?>
  <?define ProductVersion.Build="33"?>
  <?define ProductVersion="4.4.8.33"?>
  ....
</Include>
```

Then you can include and use those version numbers in the main wxs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?include Version.wxi ?>
  <?define UpgradeCode="GUID"?>
  <Product Id="*" 
        Name="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion.Major).$(var.ProductVersion.Minor)" 
        Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Language="1033" 
        Manufacturer="$(var.Company)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
```

Generate the Version.wxi just before you compile your wix project. For example modify the .wixproj file to add a target which does that.

Comment: Finally a working answer that I can use to configure Jenkins. Thanks!