# WiX: how to set version from .NET Assembly?

Tags: wix, version

I have set Product Version from .NET Assembly as it was described by Rob Mensching here
[How can I set the WiX installer version to the current build version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626033/how-can-i-set-the-wix-installer-version-to-the-curent-build-version)

But when I try to build the installer I have get an error:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE24: ProductVersion: 11.12001.1693.25097 is an invalid version string
```

How to solve this problem?
Thnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you get the error, is that the version number is not valid as a `ProductVersion` for a MSI package.

```
<major>.<minor>.<build>
```

`major` has a maximum value of 255

`minor` has a maximum value of 255

`build` has a maximum value of 65,535

Note: If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it is little bit strange: MS has made 4-parts version in NET and restricted it in MSI.

Comment: @Oleg - you are right. The reason for this might be that the Windows Installer technology is quite old.

Comment: [Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version. If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx).