# Winform App Version After Installation is Always 0.0.0.0

Tags: c#, winforms, wix, version

I have a Winform Application (c# & .Net 4.0). For deployment I use Wix installer. After installation the program shows Version 0.0.0.0. Where am I doing a mistake?

In my project I changed AssemblyInfo like this (so it should automatiacly generate version when I build):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.*")]
```

In WIX I bind version like this:

```
<?define ProductVersion="!(bind.FileVersion.IUTexe)"?>
<?define UpgradeCode="GUID"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product 
Id="*" 
Name="Installer Update Test" 
Language="1033" 
Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" 
Manufacturer="Manufacturer" 
UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
...
```

As said, after installation, Windows shows Verion as 0.0.0.0.

[image: Version]

Anyone had simmilar problem?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: When I try this in code:

```
var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
label2.Text = String.Format("My Application Version {0}", version);
```

It shows the correct version:

[image: Version]

EDIT 2:
This is how it shows in properties:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this with a pre-VS2012 Setup project.  There's a installer-specific version number that is separate from the version number of the installed assembly.  In a VS2010 Setup project there was a place to enter this version number, and if I remember right, I had to manually make it match the app's version number.

Comment: @adv12 Do you maybe remember, how you did it?

Comment: In a VS2010 Setup project, I think this property was called "Version" in the PropertyGrid that showed when you selected the Setup project in Solution Explorer.  I don't know how to specify it in WiX.  Does this question work for you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626033/how-can-i-set-the-wix-installer-version-to-the-curent-build-version

Comment: I followed that answer in the first place...but, still can't get the Version to show as it should. As I added in Edit above, when I call System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version I get the correct value...