# Can I read AssemblyFile information in Inno Setup

Tags: .net, installation, inno-setup

I would like to read these three values from my application.exe in my Inno Setup script.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("My Great Application")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("9.3.2")]
```

Does anyone know how this might be accomplished?

I know I can get the last one using [GetFileVersion("path/to/greatapp.exe")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357803/automated-build-version-number-with-wix-inno-setup-and-vs2008/358720#358720)
is there something similar for the first two?

Comment: I don't think that's doable as those attributes are .NET specific. Unless you write your own extension to achieve that goal. So I end up with hard coding them in my script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`GetStringFileInfo()` function provided by the Inno Setup Preprocessor (ISPP)](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getstringfileinfo) as follows:

1. `GetStringFileInfo("path/to/greatapp.exe", "CompanyName")`
2. `GetStringFileInfo("path/to/greatapp.exe", "ProductName")`
3. `GetStringFileInfo("path/to/greatapp.exe", "FileVersion")`

As you have already mentioned, you can use the `GetFileVersion()` function instead of #3 above.

Also, have a look at the `ISPPBuiltins.iss` script file included with your Inno Setup installation. It contains a `GetFileCompany()` function to use instead of #1 above and you can implement #2 above in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Inno Setup but I guess it supports custom actions like the other setup tools (Visual Studio, Wix, InstallShield or Wise).

So, you will need to create a custom action to read this information from  the assembly. In your custom action, you need to add the following code to fetch the assembly attributes:

```
Assembly assembly  = Assembly.LoadFrom (@"path\to\greatapp.exe");
object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(true);

if (attributes.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (object o in attibutes) 
    {
        //Do Something with the attribute
    }
}
```

Comment: It can take a lot of effort, as usually Inno Setup extensions are not authored in .NET, which means you need to parse the file manually on your own to query the attributes.

Comment: I stumbled across this somewhere and this seems to work:
#define MyAsmVersion 
GetStringFileInfo("C:\ProjectFolder\bin\Release\" + ExeName,"Assembly 
Version")
It seemed to need a space between 'Assembly' and 'Version'