# Using GetStringFileInfo in Setup section of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

After referencing [GetStringFileInfo post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433106/361100), I try to read Assembly information and apply `AppName` and `FileVersion` to Inno Setup script as below.

But compiled installation wizard shows just `"GetStringFileInfo("{#RootDirectory}Sample.exe","Title")"` as a software title. The `GetStringFileInfo` was not *processed* at all. How can I make it run correctly?

```
#define RootDirectory "bin\Release\"

[Setup]
AppName=GetStringFileInfo("{#RootDirectory}Sample.exe","Title")
AppVersion=GetStringFileInfo("{#RootDirectory}Sample.exe","FileVersion")
```

Note that I'm using Script Studio and the file resides in `setup.iss` which created by Inno Setup wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetStringFileInfo` is a preprocessor function. A syntax  for an [inline call of a preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) is:

```
AppName={#GetStringFileInfo(RootDirectory + "Sample.exe", "Title")}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative approach based on the [example](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/ISPPExample1.iss) provided with Inno Setup. Their code shows:

```
#define AppVersion GetFileVersion(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "MyProg.exe")

[Setup]
AppVersion={#AppVersion}
VersionInfoVersion={#AppVersion}
```

I have cut out the rest of the example. Notice that the call to `GetFileVersion` was done outside of the `[Setup]` section. The other answer has a more direct way to do it within the `[Setup]` section.

Comment: I was not aware of that approach. Would have been nice if it was in the example files. Shall I add your answer to mine? Or just remove mine?

Comment: Any better now? Feel free to tweak.