# Extracting application version number using Inno Setup (but excluding the fourth number)

Tags: inno-setup

I have been reading with interest about using API calls to extract information from the executable during compilation of the setup file. Example: [Using GetStringFileInfo in Setup section of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361199/using-getstringfileinfo-in-setup-section-of-inno-setup)

In my script I have the following:

```
[ISPP]
; Please, don't edit this section manually if you don't know what are you doing.
#define DataDir "{userappdata}\Meeting Schedule Assistant"
#define CommonDataDir "{commonappdata}\Meeting Schedule Assistant"
#define AppVerText "18.1.5"
#define AppURL "http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk"
#define AppPublisher "Andrew Truckle"
```

At the moment, I use the above like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Meeting Schedule Assistant
AppPublisher={#AppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#AppURL}
AppSupportURL={#AppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#AppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\Meeting Schedule Assistant
DefaultGroupName=Meeting Schedule Assistant
SourceDir=..\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Release
; NOTE: Paths are now RELATIVE to ..\Release
; NOTE: But NOT for #includes
OutputDir=..\..\inno\Output
OutputBaseFilename=MeetSchedAssistSetup
AppCopyright=Andrew Truckle © 2003 - 2018
AppVersion={#AppVerText}
VersionInfoVersion={#AppVerText}
VersionInfoCompany={#AppPublisher}
VersionInfoDescription=Meeting Schedule Assistant
VersionInfoTextVersion={#AppVerText}
VersionInfoCopyright=Andrew Truckle © 2003 - 2018
```

I have cut alot of it out. I just wanted to show you what I am doing. Now, my executable has the following version information:

[image: Version Info]

Given the above setup, is it possible for me to extract the **version number**, but, only the **18.1.5** bit (I don't show the fourth value as it is usually used for beta increments internally).

I don't want to overcomplicate my script. It is is going to be easier to just change my `ISPP` value for `AppVerText`  I will. But if I could automate it it would reduce one maintenance issue.

## Update

Based on the answer I added this code:

```
#define AppVerText() \
   ParseVersion('..\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Release\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe', Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
   Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])
```

I tried to change it to use `{#SetupSetting('SourceDir')}\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe` like this:

```
#define AppVerText() \
   ParseVersion('{#SetupSetting('SourceDir')}\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe', Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
   Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])
```

But it complained:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ParseVersion` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=parseversion) and then assemble a version string any way you like:

```
#define AppVerText() \
   ParseVersion('MyProg.exe', Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
   Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])

[Setup]
AppVersion={#AppVerText}
```

---

> I tried to change it to use `{#SetupSetting('SourceDir')}\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe` ... but it failed.

[`SetupSetting`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting) is a **preprocessor** function and you are using it inside a preprocessor expression, just like `ParseVersion`. So do not use `{# ... }` again to escape to preprocessor, as you are already there. This is the right syntax:

```
#define AppVerText() \
   ParseVersion(SetupSetting('SourceDir') + '\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe', \
     Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
   Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])
```

Though I'd personally use a preprocesor define like this:

```
#define SourceDir "..\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Release"
#define AppVerText() \
   ParseVersion(SourceDir + '\Meeting Schedule Assistant.exe', \
     Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
   Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])

[Setup]
SourceDir={#SourceDir}
AppVersion={#AppVerText}
```

---

Finally, notice that these code examples make use of an array called [`Local`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=localarray). That's why `AppVerText` is declared as a parameter-less macro (note the empty brackets after `AppVerText`), rather than a mere variable. Variable declarations do not have the `Local` array, while macro declaration do.