# Add Version to SetupWindowTitle of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

The default Title of a Inno Setup Form is

```
Setup - %1
```

where %1 will be replaced by **AppName** from [Setup]-Section. I want to add the Version like this

```
Setup - MyProgramm 2.07.5
```

I've already managed to change the title by adding the [Messages]-Section and define the **SetupWindowTitle**. But this is fixed and i can't add the version string.

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Setup - {AppName} {AppVersion}
```

This will result in

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've found my mistake. The right syntax is

```
[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
```

And define some parameters at the beginning

```
#define MyAppName "MyProgram"
#define MyAppVersion GetStringFileInfo("package\MyProgram.exe", "FILEVERSION")

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`AppVersion` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appversion):

```
[Setup]
AppVersion=2.07.5
```

The value gets automatically into the `SetupWindowTitle` (indirectly via the default value of [`AppVerName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appvername)).

*You need Inno Setup 5.6 or newer.*

---

You can also read the version from the executable:

```
[Setup]
AppVersion={#GetFileVersion(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "MyProg.exe")}
```

See:

- [Using GetStringFileInfo in Setup section of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49361199/850848)
- [How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to my application version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498750/850848)