# automated build inno setup error

Tags: installation, inno-setup

This question is regarding getting version directly from assembly. I have followed instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357803/automated-build-version-number-with-wix-inno-setup-and-vs2008)

My script looks as follow.

```
#define MyAppName "Keyboard Trader"
#define SrcApp "Keyboard Trader.exe"
#define FileVerStr GetFileVersion(SrcApp)
#define StripBuild(str VerStr) Copy(VerStr, 1, RPos(".", VerStr)-1)
#define AppVerStr StripBuild(FileVerStr)
```

But while compiling script it throws following Error

```
Compile started: Tuesday, Oct 11 2011 at 01:15 AM
---
Compiling script with Inno Setup 5.4.2 (a)
---
[ISPP] Preprocessing.
---------------------
Compile Error!
Line: 12
**Error: [ISPP] Actual parameter VerStr is not of the declared type.**
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Neither your script excerpt here nor the accepted answer on the question you linked to have a reference to VerStr on line 12. Can you post the full script you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetFileVersion() is returning a blank string as it can't find the the SrcApp  path.
Try specifying a fully qualified path or using:

```
#define SrcApp AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Keyboard Trader.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. By the way just curious how did you realize that it returns empty string?

Comment: I ran it and gave it a valid file name to test and it worked. Removing the path caused the same error.

Comment: Sorry to  bother you again but how do you debug the script? I have a breakpoint there but I can not get the variable values at all. Because when the engine is stopped at breakpoint then evaluate constant is still disabled.

Comment: You can't debug/step through the ISPP as it's done before any compilation. The Inno IDE can only debug runtime `[Code]`.